# Proof verification: Baby Rudin Chapter 6 Exercise 4

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to prove

> If $f(x) = 0$ for all irrational $x, f(x) = 1$ for all rational $x$, prove that $f \notin \mathscr{R}$ on $[a, b]$ for any $a<b$.

My attempt:

> Suppose $f(x) = 0$ for all irrational $x$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all rational $x$. Let $[a, b]$ be an arbitrary chosen real-valued interval. To show that the Dirichlet function is not Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$, by the discussion on Page $121$, it suffices to show that $\int_a^{-b} f(x)\,dx \ne \int_a^{-b} f(x)\,dx$, where $\int_a^{-b} f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{-a}^b f(x)\,dx$ are lower and upper Riemann integrals of $f$ over $[a, b]$, respectively. Note that
> \begin{equation}\tag{4.1}
>     \int_{a}^{-b} f(x)\,dx = \inf U(P, f) \quad and \quad \int_{-a}^b f(x)\,dx = \sup L(P, f)
> \end{equation}
> where the $\sup$ and the $\inf$ in (4.1) are taken over all partitions $P$ of $[a, b]$. Now, corresponding to any partition $P$ of $[a, b]$, due to the orientation of the Dirichlet function (and the density of rationals in $\mathbb{R}$), we have
> \begin{align*}
>     U(P, f) &= \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \; \Delta x_i = \underbrace{\Delta x_i+\Delta x_i+\dots+\Delta x_i}_{n \textrm{ summands}} = n \Delta x_i \quad \textrm{where } n\ge 1 \\
>     L(P, f) &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \; \Delta x_i = 0
> \end{align*}
> where $M_i = \sup f(x)$ and $m_i = \inf f(x)$ for $x_{i-1}\le x \le x_i$. Therefore,
> \begin{equation*}
>     \int_{a}^{-b} f(x)\,dx = \inf \{n \Delta x_i, n \Delta x_i, \dots\} \ne \int_{-a}^{b} f(x)\,dx = \sup \{0, 0, \dots\} = 0
> \end{equation*}
> since $n \Delta x_i \ne 0$ by construction and $n \ge 1$.

Can someone please verify the proof above and suggest how it might be improved? This is my very first proof pertaining to integrals, so it is quite possible that there are some major mistakes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake is $\sum M_i\Delta x_i=b-a$, not $n\Delta x_i$. (It is $\Delta x_1+\Delta x_2+...+\Delta x_n$).  Otherwise your proof is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here I provide another way to word it.

The proposed function is not Riemann integrable because $U(P,f)\neq L(P,f)$ for every partition $P$.

Let $P$ be a partition of the interval $[a,b]$. That is to say, $P$ is a finite set of bounded and disjoint intervals whose union coincides with $I = [a,b]$. Then we may claim that
\begin{align*}
U(P,f) = \sum_{J\in P;J\neq\varnothing}\left(\sup_{x\in J}f(x)\right)|J| = \sum_{J\in P;J\neq\varnothing}|J| = |[a,b]| = b - a
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
L(P,f) = \sum_{J\in P;J\neq\varnothing}\left(\inf_{x\in J}f(x)\right)|J| = \sum_{J\in P;J\neq\varnothing}0\times|J| = 0
\end{align*}

whence we conclude that $U(P,f)\neq L(P,f)$ just as it has been claimed, and we are done.